# Use Virtual Machine Extension against multiple VMs

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure

With Terraform, is it possible to create a single Virtual Machine Extension and use it against multiple VMs?  What happens when I destroy (using Terraform) one of the VMs that I used the extension on?

UPDATE: I was able to determine that you can't do what I was wanting to which is to create a single CSE and use it against multiple machines.  One of the properties of the a CSE is the name of the computer and if you were to change that after the CSE is created, it will re-create the CSE.  Not the behavior I was looking for.

Comment: Do you need to use Terraform? You can quickly write a Powershell script to do the same task.

Comment: @ManjunathRao I would be interested in learning more about what your approach would be on this.

Comment: I would like to know what you are trying to do.

Comment: @ManjunathRao we have a script that we use to configure all of the security settings in the OS at deployment time.  It is optimal to do this at deployment time, before the system is even able to be used for the first time.  We execute this script using a Custom Script Extension.  It would be nice if we could have a single script extension that could be called by each VM we create instead of creating a script extension for each VM.  BTW...it works on Windows and Linux.  Here is a link to it: https://github.com/plus3it/watchmaker

Comment: with Azure, you can pass custom scripts to the virtual machines AT the time of deployment or after creating the VM. If you have a list of virtual machines, then you can just execute the CSE against each of the virtual machines using a for loop or something.

Comment: @ManjunathRao that does not seem to lend well to the paradigm of DevOps CI/CD.  In the portal, you can't create a CSE outside of the creation of a VM...therefor associating it to the VM.  In Terraform, each time you reference a CSE with a different VM name, it creates a new CSE.